# Can you use Touch ID to bypass system password prompts?

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-id

Touch ID on my new MacBook Pro is pretty great, but I only seem to be able to use it to unlock the machine, not bypass/replace my system password once I'm in.

Is there a way to enable this?

Comment: Have you completed the setup for Touch ID?  If so, you should be able to use it to make purchases with iTunes, iBooks, Apple Pay, Safari, etc.

Comment: @fsb Yes, and it works fine for those things. It seems that the app showing the password prompt has to specifically allow for it— the newest Xcode allows TouchID to replace local password, but not to get the dev password out of the keychain. I suppose that's coming sometime in the future?

Comment: I would agree.  The api is new and dev's still have to incorporate it into their applications (for example, [this sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/KeychainTouchID/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple).

Comment: Great question! I still have to type in my password whenever I want to change system settings, install new applications, ... Using TouchID for those tasks would be great.

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to use it for things like deleting an app from the Applications folder and occasionally installing software. It seems to be related to whether a developer has implemented it yet or not. In the past few months, I have had the option more frequently, but still only about 30-50% of the time.